# No puedo guardar los datos de un request de Alamofire en una variable global

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Tengo un problema al hacer un request con Alamofire. Hago el request correctamente y obtengo los resultados que necesito obtener, pero cuando quiero guardar esos resultados en una variable global para poder usarlos posteriormente, no se guardan.

```
import Alamofire

class InscripcionEgresadoViewController: FormViewController {

    var jsonArray: NSArray! //Contiene el JSON de las escuelas

    var nombresEscuelas = [String]() //Array con el nombre de las escuelas, para mostrar en el picker

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        obtenerEscuelas()
        print("escuelas 1:", self.nombresEscuelas)
    }

    //Funcion para obtener las escuelas de la API
    func obtenerEscuelas(){
        var json = NSDictionary()

        Alamofire.request("API_QUE_ESTOY_USANDO").responseJSON { response in
            if let result = response.result.value {
                json = result as! NSDictionary
                self.jsonArray = json.object(forKey: "eventos") as? NSArray
                for item in self.jsonArray {
                    let escuela: String
                    escuela = (item as AnyObject).value(forKey: "nombre") as! String
                    self.nombresEscuelas.append(escuela)
                }
                print("escuelas 2:", self.nombresEscuelas)
            }
        }

        print("escuelas 3:", self.nombresEscuelas)

    }
}
```

Al hacer el print "escuelas 2" me devuelve los valores correctos que necesitos del request con Alamofire, pero en los print "escuelas 1" y "escuelas 3" me devuelve '[ ]'.

Necesito saber cómo hacer para que se guarden los datos del request en la variable global 'nombresEscuelas' para poder utilizarla en otras funcionalidades de la app.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que quieres imprimir valores que no estan disponibles aun porque la llamada al metodo de alamofire es asincronico, solo esta disponible despues que el reuqest acabe. lo que tienes que hacer es crear un funcion que actualice los datos en la vista cuando esten disponibles.

```
Alamofire.request("API_QUE_ESTOY_USANDO").responseJSON { response in
            if let result = response.result.value {
                json = result as! NSDictionary
                self.jsonArray = json.object(forKey: "eventos") as? NSArray
                for item in self.jsonArray {
                    let escuela: String
                    escuela = (item as AnyObject).value(forKey: "nombre") as! String
                    self.nombresEscuelas.append(escuela)
                }
                self.actulizarVista()
                print("escuelas 2:", self.nombresEscuelas)
            }
    }
```

y en actulizar vista actualizas tu vista. 
PD: los request son asincronicos, alamofire los hace asincronicos por defecto, para que print 1 y 3 muestren el resultado de la red el request deberia ejecutarse sincronicamente, y esto no es una buena practica de programacion, de hecho causa rechazo en al appstore proque la UI no se puede bloquear en espera de que terminen los request. da la sensacion de que la app se bloquea, que es muy lenta e ineficiente.